# Can I use "selenium" in the axis2 web service client?

Tags: java, selenium, apache-axis, selenium-webdriver

How are you?
I made a web service client by AXIS2. It works fine.
And I needed to grab an information from web page and relay it to the server using my web service client.
So I decided to use selenium+WebDriver.

I developed it separately. So my web service client works fine and my selenium based **scraper** works fine. I confirmed it.
I merged the source but my program didn't work.
Because firefoxDriver(with Xvfb solution) or HtmlUnitDriver didn't work properly.
I tested it again by separated program, and each program worked fine.

Can I run selenium code in the axis2 based web service client?
Do I need to set something?

Comment: Both are two different thing.I dnt think thr must be some issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. 
I should have replaced httpcore-4.0.jar with httpcore-4.3.jar
Because Selenium use httpcore-4.3.jar

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=3575